Error Encountered When Dynamically Adding Attribute to Razor Component in C# Blazor
I have a Differ_Board.razor file with the following content:
<div class="dsb-container" draggable="true">
    <BoardHeader></BoardHeader>
</div>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public DashBord_Info Dash_Channel_Info { get; set; }
}


BoardHeader
<div class="dsb-title">
    <div style="display: flex;
                        align-items: center;
                        justify-content: center;">
        <span>@Title</span>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; } = "Test";
}


I am using the following method to dynamically add the Dash_Channel_Info variable:
RenderFragment<DashBord_Info> renderFragment = value => builder =>
{
    builder.OpenComponent(0, Type.GetType($"{namespaceName}.{dashboardType}"));
    builder.AddAttribute(1, "Dash_Channel_Info", value);
    builder.CloseComponent();
};

I have confirmed that the variable is correctly passed, but <BoardHeader></BoardHeader> triggers the following error:
Unhandled exception rendering component: InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': ');"' is not a valid attribute name.
The error disappears when I remove builder.AddAttribute(1, "Dash_Channel_Info", value);.
But I need to use AddAttribute for dynamic generation.
I need assistance in resolving this issue. Thank you.

I cannot add  in the same way because it varies with different files.
